# jQuery setinterval is not working. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.image_slider', function() {
    setInterval(slider(this), 10000);
});
function slider(that){
  console.log(that);
}
```

Anyone can please tell me Why this function is not working and How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

window.setInterval executes the parameter after the given time. Therefore you should execute it as such:

```
setInterval ( myFunction, 1000 );
```

Or

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.image_slider', function() {
    setInterval(function (e){
        slider (this)
    }.bind (this), 10000);
});
function slider(that){
  console.log(that);
}
```